# Pulling data from one spreadsheet and inserting it into a template?

Tags: string, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm looking for a way to take a spreadsheet full of data and move it into another spreadsheet that's set up as a faux rack diagram.

For example, I would like to take data formatted as:

```
+------+---+-------------+-------+---------+-------+
| Rack | U | Service Tag | Model | Project | Owner |
+------+---+-------------+-------+---------+-------+
```

And insert into a new spreadsheet where "Rack" is a preexisting column header, "U" is a value in the first column, and the other four cells are merged together into one cell. So:

```
+-----+----+---------+--------+---------+----------+
| 566 | 36 | 1234567 | Server | Project | John Doe |
+-----+----+---------+--------+---------+----------+
```

would be converted to:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
|  U  | 001 | 002 | ... | 555 |    566   | 567 | ... |  n  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| 042 |     |     |     |     |          |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| 041 |     |     |     |     |          |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| ... |     |     |     |     |          |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| 037 |     |     |     |     |          |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| 036 |     |     |     |     | John Doe |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     | Server   |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     | Project  |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |     | 1234567  |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| 035 |     |     |     |     |          |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| ... |     |     |     |     |          |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| 002 |     |     |     |     |          |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| 001 |     |     |     |     |          |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+
```

where the first row and column are already defined.

Is there any way to automate this, or am I just stuck doing it manually?

I would have no problem doing it manually if there weren't over 900 entries that needed to be ported over.

Comment: it's a simple`vlookup()` formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"simple" in *simple `vlookup()` formula* seems a little understated to me. Assuming your matrix is in a different sheet with `U` in A1, then in B2 copied across and down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B$1&"|"&$A2,Sheet1!$H:$I,2,0),"")
```

with wrapping should work, provided your data sheet (say Sheet1 with ColumnA for `Rack`) has in H1:

```
=A1&"|"&TEXT(B1,"000")
```

and in I1:

```
=F1&CHAR(10)&D1&CHAR(10)&E1&CHAR(10)&C1
```

with both copied down to suit.